# jQuery slide stopped triggering events in Chrome 61.0.3163.100

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Three days ago this used to print console output when moving the slider (in Firefox nightly):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').slider({
    slide: function() {
      console.log('slide');
    },
    change: function() {
      console.log('change');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="slider0" name="slider0"/>
```

Today when I try it (in Chrome 61.0), it doesn't log anything to the console. Did I miss something, or is it some type of update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that `<input/>` is that it's not intended to use as a slider with jQuery UI. This works on regular input sliders, and without jQuery UI:

```
$(function() {
  var prevVal = {};
  $('.slider').on('change mousemove', function () {
    var slider = $(this);
    if (slider.val() != (prevVal[slider.attr('id')] || 0)) {
      prevVal[slider.attr('id')] = slider.val();
      slider.trigger('slide');
    }
  });
  $('.slider').on('slide', function () {
    console.log('Sliding:', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write slider like this

`$("#installs").slider({min: 0,max: 500,step: 10,slide: function (event, ui){console.log("slide");},change:function(event,ui{console.log("updatge");}});`